# How to keep jquery change() from firing after clicking on a clear button

Tags: jquery

I've got a search UI with 1 - 5 input boxes that cause an ajax action on their change() event.

I've also got a 'clear criteria' button that should clear the input boxes when clicked.  This works properly, but I've got one side effect that I'd like to be rid of.

If the user has entered data in a search input, but not left the field yet (ie change() hasn't fired), and they click the 'clear criteria', this causes the change to fire and the ajax action occurs, then the input boxes clear.

I would like to stop the change() from happening if the user clicks on the 'clear' button.

I started writing the `serachChangeHandler` function, but haven't figured out how identify if the inputbox is losing the focus to the `.ui-clear` button.

**My question is:**  Can I tell in the change handler where the focus is going, or should I be approaching the problem from a different direction?

---

My relevant javascript looks like this:

```
function displayResults(data) {
    $('.searchResults').html(data);
}

function searchChangeHandler(e) {
    ajaxSearch();
}

function ajaxSearch() {
    $('#selectedRecord').empty();
    if (isSearchable()) {
        var myForm = $('#searchForm');
        $.post(myForm.URL, myForm.serialize(), displayResults);
    } else {
        $('.searchResults').empty();
    }
}

function displayRecord(data) {
    $('#selectedRecord').html(data);
}

function searchResultClick(e) {
    $('.searchResult').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $.ajax({
        url: this.id,
        success: displayRecord,
        dataType: "html"
    });
}

function clearSearchClick() {
    $('.search input:text').val("");
    toggleClearButton(false);
    $('.searchResults').empty();
    $('.first').focus();
}

function isSearchable() {
    var allCrit = "";
    $('.search input:text').each(function () {
        allCrit += $(this).val();

    });
    return allCrit !== "";
}

function toggleClearButton(callback) {
    $('.ui-clear').toggleClass("clear-enabled", callback);
}

$(function () {
    toggleClearButton(isSearchable());
    $('.ui-clear').click(clearSearchClick);
    $('.search input:text').focusout(searchChangeHandler);
    $('.search input:text').keyup(function () { toggleClearButton(isSearchable()); });

    $(document).keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            ajaxSearch();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an idea using `setTimeout`

```
function clearSearchClick(){
    $('.search input:text').val('');
}

function searchChangeHandler(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if( isSearchable() )
        {
            // Fire your ajaxSearch() function
        }
    }, 500);
}

$(function(){
    $('.ui-clear').click(clearSearchClick);
    $('.search input:text').focusout(searchChangeHandler);
});
```

**Update:** Also in your `$(document).keypress(...)` you should call `searchChangeHandler()` function instead of directly calling the `ajaxSearch()` function because `searchChangeHandler()` is checking the input's state and firing `ajaxSearch()` after timeout.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uHdTf/4/).

Comment: Wow! I've got a down vote but would be a grate help if you (whoever you are) tell me my mistake so I can learn and will try to make it right or delete it.

Comment: @scott-pascoe, glad to know that it helped but i was confused because I got a down vote on a right (in my opinion) answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: @scott-pascoe, No you didn't but maybe someone else. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this bit is causing the problem:

```
$('.search input:text').focusout(searchChangeHandler);
```

And this function here, which gets called:

```
function searchChangeHandler(e) {
    ajaxSearch();
}
```

*  EDIT ****
Should be able to Remove both of these functions and the problem should go away!

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't even come close to solving the problem.  I want to fire ajaxSearch, aka searchChangeHandler when the user normally leaves the input field. I just don't want to fire it when they are clicking the 'clear' button.